# browser-sync : scripts won't load from parent dir

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, npm-live-server

I'm trying to get *browser-sync* to work in my project instead of using *live-server*

The app structure looks like this:

```
personal-app
├── node_modules
└── src
    ├── app
    │   └── app.ts
    └── index.html
```

in *index.html* the scripts are loaded from **node_modules** dir

```
<script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

when I use **live-server**, it loads the scripts and works fine, but since I moved to browser-sync, the scripts don't load. here is the code in *gulpfile.js*:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./src"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch(sassfiles, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(htmlfiles).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

when I give the src path as base dir `baseDir: "./src"`
the site works but the scripts don't load

[image]

but when I change it to `baseDir: "./"`

The site gives me **Cannot GET /**, however when I add "/src" to the url in chrome like so "http://localhost:3000/src", it works.

so the problem here is that *browser-sync* won't load the scripts from the parent folder of its **baseDir**.

I need a way to configure *browser-sync* to launch from its `baseDir : "./"` but load the main page **index.html** from sub folder.

is this possible with browser-sync?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [browser-sync documentation](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/)

**baseDir** can take multiple paths. I added the src folder where index.html exists.

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: ["./", "./src"]   //added multiple directories 
        }
    });
    gulp.watch(sassfiles, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(htmlfiles).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this f**d up me 3 hours :).

Comment: this just saved my life i was going crazy

Comment: Thanks, so we can use infinite number of multiple directories? Or it is like symlinking a root path `./` to `./src`?

Comment: Further, if you use `directory: true` to show dir listing as the startpage, browserSync uses the **first** dir in `baseDir` for the listing. In this case `"./"`

Comment: It should be noted that current version of docs (as of Feb 2021), do **not** explicitly mention this; this is rather inferred instead…